# uwp - 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, binding, uwp

I'm trying to create UWP chat using MVVM. I keep getting this error:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

in my view model in here:

```
public void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

this function occurs every time a value is set to the string property that bond to the TextBlock.Text property in the xaml;

i tried inserting the TextBlock  (that the vm was bond to its text property)  in the view model and remove all the binding in the xaml and use this function:

```
private async Task LoadMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            ChatBox += $"{sender}: {message} \n";
        });
    }
```

still the same, only now the exception is thrown in the above function.

I found anther dispatcher while searching for answer but it seems that uwp doesn't recognize it and mark it with red under-line:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            //my code           
        });
```

I tried :

```
await CoreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => 
        {
            ChatBox += $"{sender}: {message} \n";
        });
```

but then i got

> an object reference is required for the non-static field, method

so I created a static class the holds this function :

```
public static void UpdateTextBlock(TextBlock textBlock, string sender, string message)
    {

        textBlock.Text = $"{sender}: {message}";
    }
```

and inserting it to this dispatcher. still no-go. still: an object reference is required for...

i really want it to be MVVM, but any solution that works would be a bless.

**EDIT**

today i tried moving back to the binding and mvvm pattern. i was wrapping the LoadMessage function in task like this:

```
private async Task<bool> LoadMessage(string sender, string message)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            TextBindingProperty += $"{sender}: {message} \n";
            flag = true;
        });

        return flag;
    }

_hubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", async (sender, message) =>
        {
            var result = await Task.Run(() => LoadMessage(sender, message));
        });
```

same exception only in class : MyView.g.cs

in this method:

```
public static void Set_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_Text(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock obj, global::System.String value, string targetNullValue)
        {
            if (value == null && targetNullValue != null)
            {
                value = targetNullValue;
            }
            obj.Text = value ?? global::System.String.Empty; //in this line!!!
        }
    };
```

My view model implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public class UserViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private string chatBox;

    public string ChatBox
    {
        get { return chatBox; }
        set { chatBox = value; Notify(nameof(ChatBox)); }
    }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

the xaml element that is bond to this property looks like this:

```
 <TextBlock Name="chatTbl"  Text="{x:Bind userViewModel.ChatBox, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: instead of showing these, just show us what your ViewModel (all of it, if not too large) looks like now and what is the current error. Also, show the xaml part too.

Comment: Give this a try: In Load Message use the CoreApplication.MainView..... And wrap the PropertyChanged in another Task (Not an UI Task)

Comment: @TheTanic In LoadMessage is it not what i did? LoadMessage returns Task and inside it i used the CoreApplication.MainView. what do you mean by wrapping the propertyChanged in anther task? can you show code? thx

Comment: @Muzib i edited the post for your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

so battling to make the chat work this was the problem:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView
```

since the chat is in a different view than the main page it couldn't find the binding or the xaml element.

what my friend realize that in order to make changes in other view you need to get its object so, we added this property to the view model:

```
  public CoreApplicationView CurrentView { get; set; }
```

when launching the chat room view we set the property:

```
public UserViewModel userViewModel;
    public ChatRoom(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.userViewModel = userViewModel;
        userViewModel.ChatTbl = chatTbl;


        userViewModel.CurrentView = CoreApplication.GetCurrentView();//this line

    }
```

now when we need to make changes in the view we use:

```
 _hubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", async (sender, message) =>
        {

            await CurrentView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ChatTbl.Text += $"{sender}: {message} \n";
            });
        });
```

so instead `await CoreApplication.MainView`

use `await CurrentView.CoreWindow`

hope this would help someone i know it would have helped me

Answer (score 1):

Your `LoadMessage` is an asynchronous method, you did not need to put it in `Task.Run`. You could directly call it like the following:

```
_hubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", async (sender, message) =>
    {
        var result = await LoadMessage(sender, message);
    });
```

If you have to put it in `Task.Run`, you could call it like this:

```
_hubProxy.On<string, string>("SendMessage", async (sender, message) =>
    {
        var result = await Task.Run(async() => await LoadMessage(sender, message));
    });
```